# spark version 3.0.1 run enableHiveSupport will rasie pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am using hadoop 2.10.x + hive 3.1.x + spark 3.0.1 and trying to load log file into hive by pyspark.
I followed the code from spark document to connect to hive.

```
warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

but it always raise pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: <exception str() failed>.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_extra.py", line 16, in <module>
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
  File "/usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 191, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 134, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: <exception str() failed>
```

If I don't add config `enableHiveSupport`, this python script can run but can only connect to built-in hive.
I have put `hive-site.xml` in spark/conf.
Now I don't know how to connect to my hive by spark.